# How to check if a username is already used in PHP using sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm working on building my own login/registration website using php and a Azure database and there is one thing I can't figure out: How to check if a username is taken. My code keeps coming back at: `error retrieving username` and I don't understand why, and how to fix it.
Here is the current code for my registration:

```
<?php
    //Database connection file
    include_once("config.php");

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $conpassword = $_POST['conpassword'];

    $npassword = password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if($password !== $conpassword) {
        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Passwords don't match";
        header("location: ../register.php");
        exit();
    }

    $sql2 = "SELECT username FROM Gebruikers WHERE username = (?)";
    $params2 = array($username, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql2, $params2);

    if ($stmt2 === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        exit();
    }

    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt2);

    if ($row_count != 0) {
        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Error retrieving username";
        header("location: ../register.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row_count > 0) {
            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Username is already used";
            header("location: ../register.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Gebruikers(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $params = array($username, $npassword);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }else{
        echo "Registration completed!";
        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Registration completed!";
        header("location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

I hope somebody knows the answer to my question!
Thanks in advance! Thomas

Comment: `Select` data from DB by username and password the check the does it exist

Comment: @D-Shih sorry the code I uploaded was my old code. i'll change it.

Comment: Just usernane should be unique actually

Comment: I've updated my code. this is the current version

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways of doing this. Perhaps the easiest if to specify that the username is unique in SQL Server. 
You can run this command in SQL Server Management Studio

```
ALTER TABLE Gebruikers ADD CONSTRAINT unique_username UNIQUE (username)
```

If you do that then the line

```
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

will kick off if the same user name is used again.

Comment: This works! But how do I convert the error into a suitable message, like with my `$_SESSION['errMSg'];`

Answer (score 0):

Your username column should be unique. If this is the case, a second insert will fail (if the name is already present you can't insert it again if the column is unique). In this case you have one of two options. Either you can:

1. Look ahead of time to make sure the username is free

   ```
   select count(*) from Gebruikers where username = ?
   ```

If the query doesn't return 0 the name is taken. If the count is 0 then do the insert. If it's 1 then add an error to show the user.

2. Put your insert statement in a try-catch block and assume the username is not taken, letting your database insert fail if it is taken, catching the exception and adding an error to show to the user (if the query failed because of a constraint violation on the column the name is taken).

**EDIT**

I didn't mean your query had to change to what I wrote. Conceptually the two approaches are as follows.

First possibility on create user form submit

```
check username availability with a query
if it's available
    insert a row for username,password
else
    add an error message / return an error response telling the user that the name is taken
```

Second possibility on create user form submit

```
try
    insert a row for username,password
catch constraint violation exception
    add an error message / return an error response telling the user that the name is taken
```

Personally I think the first option is better (look ahead and see if the username is there).

Other than that, you should rethink your design. It's a bit confusing to read through. For example, something more like

```
$addUserStatus = -1; // assume error
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// confirm password
$conpassword = $_POST['conpassword'];

$errors = array();

// here you need to decide what a valid username is, surely not everything is valid
if (!validUsername($username)) {
    $errors[] = "Invalid username entered: " . $username;
}

if (!validPassword($password) {
    $errors[] = "Insert a password that is (your rules here)";
}

if ($password !== $conpassword) {
    $errors[] = "Passwords don't match";
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
    // the user entered valid data, check to see if the username is taken
    $usernameStatus = available($username);
    if ($usernameStatus === 1) {
        $addUserStatus = addUser($username, $password);
        if ($addUserStatus === -1) {
            $errors[] = "An internal server error prevented the user from being added.";
        }
    } else if ($usernameStatus === 0) {
        $errors[] = "Username " . $username . " is taken, please choose another.";
    } else /* usernameStatus is -1 here */ {
        $errors[] = "Database access error, try again later".
    }
}

if (count($errors) === 0 && addUserStatus === 1) {
    // user was addded
} else {
    // do something with all the errors
}

function validUsername($username) {
    // TODO your logic here; what is a valid username for your app?
}

function validPassword($password) {
    // TODO your logic here; what password rules do you have? min characters? special characters?
}

function available($username) {
    // TODO implement a check to see if the username is available. Either select count like in my example and check that the value is 0 (it's available) or select * and see how many rows were returned (0 for available username)
    // here instead of just dying if $stmt === false (failure) either throw an exception or return an error code that makes sense to you, so for example instead of just returning true / false you could return 0 for not available, 1 for available and -1 for error; then you can handle this from the caller.
}

function addUser($username, $password) {
    // TODO hash the password, add the username and hashed password to the database
    // return 1 if user added, -1 for error
}
```

Comment: if I change my SQL Statement to your option1 I still get the SQL error because I made the username Unique. Could you maybe show me an example of how to use this properly?

Comment: @ThomasAdema I updated my answer with some example code for you to expand on. I hope it helps you

Comment: This seems like a great and very detailed explaination! Thanks a lot. I will try to use this and let you know how it worked out!

Comment: `function available($username) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Gebruikers WHERE username = ?";
    $params = array($username, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($stmt != 0) {
        $errors[] = "Username is not available"
    }else{
        
    }
}`
so this is what you mean? or do I still do something wrong...?

Comment: @ThomasAdema more or less, yes, but your function should return something (boolean true if available false otherwise). In general, leaving this problem aside for a minute, try to break whatever it is you're doing into small, complete logical steps. In this case, you have to look into the database to see if a record exists with a given username. If it does, return false (not available); if it doesn't, return true (available).

Comment: I have tried to fit your code and my code in 1 and the only thing it lead to is a Error 500 from my Azure server :-( . I'm not really familiar with functions so perhaps I did something wrong? Can I place my new code somewhere so you can look at it? (I'm not really familiair with stack either... :-))

Comment: www.codereview.stackexchange.com only reviews code that actually works.

Comment: Exactly. @WilliamBurnham Please don't recommend Code Review if you aren't familiar with their scope. For future reference, see the [guide to Code Review for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Mast Thanks for clarifying, sorry for the bad referral. Thomas, Include your new code under your old code as an edit.